# Minimum level principal congruence subgroup coming from neat open compact subgroup

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reductive-groups

For a connected reductive group $G/\mathbb{Q}$ what is known about the minimum level such that the respective principal congruence subgroup is the intersection of a neat open compact subgroup of $G(\mathbb{A}_f)$ and $G(\mathbb{Q})$?

For $GL_2$ the answer is $3$.